# How to read Node.js API docs? What does e.g. "stat(2)" mean?

Tags: node.js

For example, let's consider [File System](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module and its [fs.stat(path, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) method. Here is a description:

> fs.stat(path, callback)
>
> Asynchronous stat(2). The callback gets two
>   arguments (err, stats) where stats is a fs.Stats object. See the
>   fs.Stats section below for more information.

What does `stat(2)` mean? It is not a link, it doesn't follow anywhere, it is just a string. How to understand it? The API documentation has gazillion of such references, what do they all mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stat(2)` is a reference to the `stat()` function in a specific POSIX revision level (which I believe is POSIX.1-2001 and also referred to as SUSv3).  See the man page for `stat(2)` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

The node.js documentation pretty much assumes you are very familiar with some parts of the POSIX library and does not offer helpful references for those who are not familiar with it (which is unfortunate in my opinion).